# Javascript: changing img src onclick only works once

Tags: javascript

This is so simple I'm not sure why I'm having trouble with it. I'm trying to imitate a flip card between two images so when clicked, it would simply change to the other image. I'm having trouble with my if/else statement because every time the image is clicked, it never makes it to the else part. In the source code of the HTML page, the src of the image is being changed but passes the if statement every time.

```
(function() {

    // attaches event handler to image
    window.onload = function() {

        var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
        image1.onclick = changeImage;
    };

    // changes image when clicked to flip from image to text and text to image
    function changeImage() {
        if (document.getElementById("image1").src = "img/top.png") {
            document.getElementById("image1").src = "img/toptext.png";
            //window.alert('hi');
        }
        else {
            window.alert('it passed');
            document.getElementById("image1").src="img/top.png";
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Check your comparison operator in your if statement, hint you arent using one

Comment: The **if** statement condition is the problem. Replace equal mark **=** to be comparison equal mark **==**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use == or === for comparison in if condition check.

using = will assign the value and always be true since the assigned string is not an empty string.

```
 function changeImage() {
        if (document.getElementById("image1").src == "img/top.png") {
            document.getElementById("image1").src = "img/toptext.png";
            //window.alert('hi');
        }
        else {
            window.alert('it passed');
            document.getElementById("image1").src="img/top.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"always be true."_ it will only be true if the assigned value is truthy

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes i agree but in this condition when the assigned string is  non empty string it will always be true correct ?

Comment: I also had to use .getAttribute("src") when doing the comparison in the if statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use == for an if comparaison

```
if (document.getElementById("image1").src = "img/top.png") {
```

change into

```
if (document.getElementById("image1").src == "img/top.png") {
```